# Removing WebView from View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have a tableView which launches a URL after the cell was pressed. I am creating webView for it:

```
var webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
view.addSubview(webView)
let request = URLRequest(url: catPictureURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
webViewDidStartLoad(webView)
```

And I have a function to create a close button in it:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    print("JUHUUU")
    var subView = UIView()
    subView.frame.size.height = 10
    subView.frame.size.width = 10
    subView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100 , height: 100)
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("CANCEL", for: [])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    webView.addSubview(subView)
    //subView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "dismiss")
}
```

I have tried in button.addTarget to close the webView and show previous screen, but the

```
action: #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview)
```

is removing `rootView` - not the `webView` (which is causing crashes). I don't really know how to get `webView` closed.
PS. I have also tried doing `#selector("dismiss")` and preparing a function with `self.dismiss` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actions target is self( which is your vc) . Set target to webView

Comment: What do you mean? I have tried using #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview). When I use use #selector("dismiss"), then i cannot refer to webView inside function.

Comment: @misi06 I mean replace “self” in “button.addTarget(self..” with webView. Target of your action should be webView not your controller

Comment: Thanks! It works. I thought self refered to button here. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Self should be changed to webView in order to close it.

```
button.addTarget(webView, action: #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```